# How to edit part of endpoint in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I'm having some trouble automating my API tests. I have to run the Test Suite on different IP adresses, without changing the whole endpoint (/api/auth part, for example, should stay there). Does anyone know how can I do this?
[That is the example I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMZAK.png)

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties/#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Project [property](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties/), say `serverName`
Then variable-ize the URL, like this:

```
http://${#Project#serverName}:8888/api/auth
```

Comment: Thanks my friend!