# Rest Mock Service on SOAPUI

Tags: rest, soapui, simulator

I am preparing a mock service where the request coming to mock server as:
http://localhost:8080/api/v01/transactions/307/events/

And hence I have configured the mock service resource path as: (And I am getting success response)
[image]

But the problem is the ID. I.e. 307. In the next/subsequent request it will come as 308,309, 100, 56 etc... which is dynamic.

My aim is can we configure the resource path as dynamic so that it whatever the ID comes, it will accept and return response?

Please advise !!!

Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: In my experience you can't. What generates the ID ? You will have to let the developer make it a constant value in the dev/test env's. The ID part is presumably not what you are testing, if it is, you can test the ID generation (that it's unique etc.) in another way.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Ex: I created a Customer and it is being saved in DB and in the DB it saved with ID(unique) and the code creates dynamic URL, takes the id from DB (as you know for each request it increments), but as you suggested, I will try if we can send the constant ID every time to simulator.

Comment: If it's per customer that's a different matter. You may be able create a property variable and use it in the url. You can then dynamically populate the property from a list before each service call. Look here (it's for SOAP not REST but in principle it should work) https://stackoverflow.com/a/70076226/3355860